# Remove all after certain character/phrase SQLITE

Tags: string, sqlite, substring, case, instr

Table in SQLITE, want to simple way to delete everything to a right of a set phrase/character in the Company_name_ column, in this case everything after "LLC":

| Company_name_ |
| --- |
| Example LLC $42 |
| Example llc,klp |
| Example LLc jim |

becomes

| Company_name_ |
| --- |
| Example LLC |
| Example llc |
| Example LLc |

Tried Set Charindex and Substr but getting syntax errors.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with string functions [`SUBSTR()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) and [`INSTR()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr).

If you want a `SELECT` query use a `CASE` expression with the operator `LIKE` to check if the column value contains `'LLC'` or not:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Company_name_ LIKE '%LLC%'
           THEN SUBSTR(
                  Company_name_,
                  1,
                  INSTR(UPPER(Company_name_), 'LLC') + LENGTH('LLC') - 1
                ) 
         ELSE Company_name_ 
       END Company_name_   
FROM tablename;
```

If you want to update the table:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Company_name_ = SUBSTR(
                      Company_name_,
                      1,
                      INSTR(UPPER(Company_name_), 'LLC') + LENGTH('LLC') - 1
                    ) 
WHERE Company_name_ LIKE '%LLC%';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=958245019de7342a700daf6db1fe1f4a).